# Facebook page private replies not working

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, messaging

I make FB page comment to private replies bot using PHP. But it can't send a message.

Comment Response JSON Object:

```
            {
                "entry": [
                {
                    "changes": [
                        {
                        "field": "feed",
                        "value": {
                            "from": {
                                "id": "2650405101652313",
                                "name": "Fojle Rabbi"},
                                "item": "comment",
                                "comment_id": "192443498065754_278556189454484",
                                "post_id": "183258478984256_192443498065754",
                                "verb": "add",
                                "parent_id": "183258478984256_192443498065754",
                                "created_time": 1540980863,
                                "post": {
                                    "type": "photo",
                                    "updated_time": "2018-10-31T10:14:23+0000",
                                    "promotion_status": "ineligible",
                                    "permalink_url": "https://www.facebook.com/FojleRabbi.bd/photos/a.183258498984254/192443498065754/?type=3",
                                    "id": "183258478984256_192443498065754",
                                    "status_type": "added_photos",
                                    "is_published": true
                                    },
                                    "message": "retest"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "id": "183258478984256",
                        "time": 1540980866
                    }
                ],
                "object": "page"
            }
```

API Call:
    https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/Comment_Id_Here/private_replies?message=hi&access_token=Access_Token_Here

Error: 
        {
       "error": {
        "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (private_replies) on node type (Comment)",
       "type": "OAuthException",
       "code": 100,
       "fbtrace_id": "GZgfwqS8TQa"
      }
    }

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Error 100 means that there is a plain syntax error in the URL you are posting to.

Comment: any suggestions for fixing this problem!

Comment: thank you for your response

Comment: Sorry, I don't really have any suggestions.

Comment: no problem. @GrumpyCrouton again thanks

Comment: This looks like you are making a GET request, but since this is supposed to _create_ something, it needs to be a POST request.

Answer (score 2):

This endpoint is deprecated on October 29, 2019. Now, you can use the new Private Replies [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/private-replies)